# Debugging firefox extension

Tags: debugging, firefox-addon

I like to make some changes to a firefox extension(DownThem All).

In that they have written Debug logs like:

```
Debug.log('<Whatever>');
```

I wanted to view those messages during execution, in order to make the changes effectively. How to view those messages (most preferably i wanted to set breakpoints and make inlace modification)?

I am running firefox 5.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f` the log file.

Or to stay in Firefox, DTA `preferences->privacy->view log`, and refresh manually or set a greasemonkey script to periodically refresh.

If you want to alter the extension, unzip the `.xpi` file to its' directory (DTA is {DD} in `<profile>/extensions`) and rename the `.xpi`, so Firefox will load the code from the directory, which you can alter at will.

For breakpoints etc, use firebug & chromebug.